# node request returns empty body

Tags: node.js, request

this is my code:

```
var request = require('request');
var j = request.jar();

request = request.defaults({jar:j,  followAllRedirects: true});


var urls =new Array();

urls["login"] = "https://www.brooklynfitzone.com/index.php/login";
urls["main"] = "https://www.brooklynfitzone.com/index.php";
urls["reserva"] = "https://www.brooklynfitzone.com/index.php/classes/set_book";

//login


request.post(urls["login"], {form:{user:'user@user.com',pass:'testpass'}},  function(err, httpResponse, html) {
    console.log(httpResponse);
    console.log(j.getCookies());
    console.log(err);
    console.log(html);
});
```

the thing is, using the correct user and password the body it returns is empty, I'm unable to get any contents.

Comment: What is the result of your logs?

Comment: @tbking https://pastebin.com/SsnX3WBk thats the output

Comment: One, yes, the body is empty, but there are some cookies being set. Two, the log output is just a part and don't show what cookies.